# LEFT JOIN on a CHARINDEX(x,y) !=0 returning a row twice where x in y more than once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join, charindex

```
SELECT EventDate,
       EventType,
       Institution_Party_id,
       IP,
       DOI,
       Usage_Count,
       User_Agent
FROM [STG].[TABLE_UE] UE

     LEFT JOIN DWH.BOT_Word_List BWL ON CHARINDEX(BWL.Word, UE.User_Agent) != 0
WHERE UE.DOI IS NOT NULL
      AND UE.Institution_Party_Id IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY EventDate,
         EventType,
         Institution_Party_id,
         IP,
         DOI,
         Usage_Count,
         User_Agent;
```

The LEFT JOIN DWH.BOT_Word_List BWL ON CHARINDEX(BWL.Word, UE.User_Agent) != 0 part of this is returning the same row multiple times, where a word in BWL.Word appears more than once in UE.User_Agent.

e.g. in BOT_Word_list, the words 'bot' and 'Google' appear. Then, in User_Agent, the words 'Googlebot/bot.html' appears.

How do I get it to return a row only once?

Somehow using group by, partition over?

Context:
Words in the Bot_Word_List that appear in user_agent indicate that the user was a bot, and not a real person. In this event, later in the procedure, I would apply a bot flag to that row. 
I would still want the 'non' bot rows to appear, hence a left join, not inner (which would not eliminate the duplicate anyway).

eg.

```
2018-01-09, ACCESS_DENIAL_FULL_VIEW, Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

2018-01-09, ACCESS_DENIAL_FULL_VIEW, Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

being returned.

Thought: would an OUTER APPLY work?

```
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT top 1 * FROM DWH.BOT_Word_List BWL WHERE CHARINDEX(BWL.Word, UE.User_Agent) != 0) BWL
```

Comment: What do you expect?  That is how `JOIN`s work.  Edit your question and qualify the column names.  It is not clear where the columns come from and that type of information is important for anyone who wants to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Change left join to inner join and try again.

Comment: Edited. An inner join will eliminate rows which don’t have text in bot_word_list in user_agent, which I don’t want. I’ll just be adding a flag to >0 later

Comment: Can you add a sample of the results you are getting? This would help to determine if GROUP BY or DISTINCT will solve your problem.

Comment: You don't explain what you want. Just that you only want 1 of (certain) left table ids on output. You don't say what else comes with them, other than giving a *wrong* query. Please read & act on [mcve].  Including PKs, FKs & other constraints, especially re cardinalities. Also: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Put such an image inline, not as a link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: PS What query can you write to return a single table with at least the data from which you could extract your desired output but with as little extra data as you can manage? And how is your desired output a function of (extracted from) that?

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration *your query* and the sample result:

```
2018-01-09, ACCESS_DENIAL_FULL_VIEW, Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

2018-01-09, ACCESS_DENIAL_FULL_VIEW, Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

I would say a simple [DISTINCT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx) clause would suffice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EventDate,
       EventType,
       Institution_Party_id,
       IP,
       DOI,
       Usage_Count,
       User_Agent
FROM [STG].[TABLE_UE] UE

     LEFT JOIN DWH.BOT_Word_List BWL ON CHARINDEX(BWL.Word, UE.User_Agent) != 0
WHERE UE.DOI IS NOT NULL
      AND UE.Institution_Party_Id IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY EventDate,
         EventType,
         Institution_Party_id,
         IP,
         DOI,
         Usage_Count,
         User_Agent;
```